# SOLVED: Set value to next *multiple of ten* if it's over the previous *multiple of ten*

Tags: javascript

For example:
If the number I have is 12.5, and i want the number to go to the next multiple of ten (20). Or if i have a number over 20 and under 30, it has to be 30.
How can I do that in JavaScript?
I can't seem to find any answers to this.

EDIT: ok little english error here, i meant multiple of ten (10, 20, 30)

EDIT 2: I have used the method in the (now marked) correct answer below, and it has solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome, user13289129 - bravely done to post! I only had my first post of a question a few days ago. Let me ask about your meaning of 'dozen' - to me, a dozen is a range of 12, so the first dozen would be 1-12, the second dozen would be 13-24, the third dozen would be 25-36, and so forth. Is that the way you are meaning 'dozen' in this question?

Comment: Can you please share more details as to a few cases with input and expected outputs?

Comment: Well that "dozen" label is throwing me off a bit, but I think you just want `Math.ceil(n/10)*10`

Comment: Woopsies, I'm not a native english speaker. I thought it was dozens but I mean tens, if that's correct

Comment: What should happen if the input is 10?

Comment: If the input is 10 it stays at 10 If it's under that, like 7, it has to be ten. If it's over 10, like 12, it has to be 20.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is great, that your solution has been solved. But please post the solution as a new answer. If it is the best (or only) answer to your question make sure to also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/316262) it, so others know this problem has a working solution.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have marked the correct answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think you're talking about round to the next *ten* rather than the next *dozen*. Use this:

```
function ceilTenRoundUp(number) {
    return Math.ceil(number/10)*10;
}


console.log(ceilTenRoundUp(12.5)); // 20
console.log(ceilTenRoundUp(22));   // 30
```